# To get Tab focus inside itemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, accordion, flex4.5, itemrenderer

I have an mx accordian in my application like.

```
    <mx:VBox horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">       
<mx:Accordion id="accSubmenu" />
    </mx:VBox>
```

Accordian has NavigatorContents as its elements..

```
<s:Group  clipAndEnableScrolling="true">
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>

<s:Scroller id="scrlSubMenu" 
horizontalScrollPolicy="off" 
hasFocusableChildren="true">
    <s:DataGroup id="lstSubMenu"
    clipAndEnableScrolling="true" 
    hasFocusableChildren="true"
    itemRenderer="renderers.SubmenuItmRndr">
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:DataGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

itemRenderer is of HoverImage as below..

```
<s:ItemRenderer clipAndEnableScrolling="true"
                autoDrawBackground="false" >
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
        <controls:HoverImage toolTip="{data.Name}" source="{'assets/' + data.IconFileName}"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

I want keyboard navigation(Tab focus) on images inside itemRenderer.. 
 Could anybody help me to get solution?